# Which Sitecore PowerShell extension version to download in Sitecore version 8.2?

Tags: powershell-extensions, powershell

I am a absolute beginner for SPE, have Sitecore 8.2, how do I download SPE in this and according to https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/appendix it says that 8.2 supports SPE version 4.1 and above. What version should I be aiming to download from https://github.com/SitecorePowerShell/Console/releases. Also is there any how to guides for this ?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Using this link you can check the version compatibility of Sitecore vs SPE.

https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/appendix

To download the initial release version i.e. 4.1, you can download it from here.

https://github.com/SitecorePowerShell/Console/releases?page=3

When you click on the Assets, you can find the appropriate package for your Sitecore instance.

Hope this helps.